# Drawing braid diagrams in Latex, t-angles.sty package

Tags: diagrams, braids

I found this extremely cool package "t-angles.sty" [(manual found here)](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/t-angles?lang=de)

which seems to fit perfectly to what I was looking for.
Unfortunately I can't figure out what's the problem in my code. 
I want to "draw" the following diagram (where the Bs and Hs are not necessary for me): 
[image]

My code in a minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[emtex]{t-angles}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\m \;=\enspace
\begin{tangles}{lccr}
\HH \id & \cd & \id & \id \\ %(1)
\HH \id & \id & \x & \id \\  %(2)
\HH \id & \hlu & \id \id \\
\HH \Cu && \cu
\end{tangles}
\]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get the following output: 
[image]
Anyone here who can help me? 
It would help a lot to understand this package. As I said, it seems to be exactly what I need!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! No idea about the package and I did not compile. But your `lcr` looks as if you do define 3 columns but you clearly fill up 4 columns. `lcr` is most probably left centered right. So start trying to add one of those more.

Comment: Regarding the `&`: You should read a bit about matrices and tables in LaTeX. Those are separators between columns. So `&&` does just show an empty column. `&    &` would yield the same. Generally talking, but I bet it is the same for this package here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks for the first hint, now its not an error anymore, the diagram just doesn't look at all like I wanted. I'll update the question! :D

Comment: Glad that helped a bit. The manual (http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/t-angles/t-manual.pdf) has only 7 pages and some examples. Maybe you start by doing those tutorials first.

Comment: Yes I tried that, and I thought I had understood the examples quite well. My code ist build upon the first example...  but thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some small improvements the output can be made close to the image. The `\hlu` command has an optional argument to set the width (e.g., `\hlu[2]`). Note that the third and fourth line have only two `&` symbols instead of three. Because the `\Cu` command is too big, the `\cu` command can be used. This leads to the following output:

[image]

Now, the `\cu` is too small. It appears that the package does not provide any customization for `\cu` or `\Cu`, so a new command should be made for that. For `\Cu` the source of the package contains the following definition:

```
\hbx(4,2){\pr@d{20,20,40,20}{b}{20,0,0,10}}
```

Using this definition it is possible to create a new command with changed numbers that result in a smaller output.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[emtex]{t-angles}

\makeatletter
\def\mycu{%
% \hbx{width,height} \pr@d{left offset,bottom offset,width,height}{oval part}{line left,top,?,length}
\hbx(1,1){\pr@d{10,10,20,10}{b}{10,0,0,5}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ 
m \;=\enspace
\begin{tangles}{llrr}
\HH \id & \cd & \id & \id \\ %(1)
\HH \id & \id & \x & \id \\  %(2)
\HH \id & \hlu[2] & \id & \id \\
\HH \mycu & & & \cu
\end{tangles}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]